# Date Format in Json request/response of an API

Tags: json, spring, api, date, datetime

I am having a Date field - startDate in my pojo.

In API request body in JSON I have to mention date in following format -

```
{
...
"startDate" : "2017-05-19T14:00:00",
...
}
```

But in the response I get the following format -

```
{
...
"startDate" : "2017-05-19 14:00:00",
...
}
```

There is no 'T' in the response JSON.

What should I do to make it consistent and have the 'T' in response as well.

Comment: let us know what you have tried so far..

Comment: more code in class include field date

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` at the time of `request`.

```
String time = "2017-05-19T14:00:00";        
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date d = sdf.parse(time);
String formattedTime = output.format(d);
System.out.println(formattedTime);
```

**OR**

you can use below code for `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` at the time of `response`.

```
String time = "2017-05-19 14:00:00";        
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date d = sdf.parse(time);
String formattedTime = output.format(d);
System.out.println(formattedTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

There two ways to achieve the result.

1. Use String in server side.So you can get the same result in both
   request and response.
2. You could convert date object into Long(millisecond).

For your information, The T is just a literal to separate the date from the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")